# Autoreleasing object returned from NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management

When a method returns an object that is taken from and NSMutableArray does the object must be autoreleased? Check the following method. Also should I autorelease the nil value?

```
-(NSObject*)getElementByID:(NSString*)ID{

    for(int i=0;i<[elements count];i++){
        NSObject *element = (NSObject*) [elements objectAtIndex:i];

        if([element.key isEqualToString:ID]){
            return [element autorelease];
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must not autorelease `element` because you are not an owner of it (you have not put a retain on it). You would have become an owner of it if you acquired it using `alloc`, `new` or `retain`. Since you acquired this object calling `objectAtIndex:`, you do not own it. See [Three Magic Words](http://robnapier.net/blog/three-magic-words-6). Calling `autorelease` here will cause a crash later do to over-release.

Your method name is incorrect and breaks KVC. A method that begins with `get` must take a pointer that will be updated with the result. This should be `elementForID:`. As noted above with the three magic words, naming in ObjC is very important to writing stable code

As a side note, it is traditional to use `id` is most cases rather than `NSObject*`. They mean slightly different things, but typically `id` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You never need to do any memory management related things to `nil`.  So, no, you should not send `autorelease` to `nil`.

You also should not need to send `autorelease` to the `element` object that you are returning from your `elements` array.   That object you are returning will remain in memory by virtue of `elements` itself having retained it.  If the calling method would like to `retain` the value that you return, it may.  But if that calling method only uses the returned value within its own scope, it is safe for it to do so without retaining it.